# Merge sort program doesn't do anything to the array that I want to sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to implement a merge sort but when I print my array in my main method it remains unmodified and I'm unsure of why that's the case. I tried printing the contents of the arrays that I split but it gave me values that I was unsure of where it was coming from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right, vector<int> arr) {
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;

    while (j < left.size() && k < right.size()) {
        if (left[j] >= right[k]) {
            arr[l] = right[k];
            k += 1;
            l += 1;
        } else {
            arr[l] = left[j];
            j += 1;
            l += 1;
        }
    }
    if (j < left.size()) {
        for (int i = j + k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            j += 1;
            arr[i] = left[j];
        }
    }
    if (k < right.size()) {
        for (int i = j + k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            k += 1;
            arr[i] = right[k];
        }
    }
}

void merge_sort(vector<int> arr) {
    int n = arr.size();
    if (n <2) {
        return;
    }
    int mid = n / 2;

    vector<int> left = vector<int>(arr.begin(), arr.end() - mid - 1);
    for (int i : left) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    vector<int> right = vector<int>(arr.begin() + mid, arr.end());
    for (int i : right) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    merge_sort(left);
    merge_sort(right);
    merge(left, right, arr);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> arr = {3, 3, 4, 6, 42, 6, 2};
    merge_sort(arr);
    for (int i : arr) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing all of your vectors by value meaning you are using a copy inside the function and outside it won't see the change.

Comment: *I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to implement a merge sort* -- If you know another language that passes values by reference, don't use another programming language as a model in writing C++ code.  C++ uses value-semantics, not reference semantics.  Those vectors are temporary when passed by value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a *copy* of the `vector` when you pass it to `merge_sort`. Any changes made to `arr` in the function will not be visible in `main`.

Instead, you need to pass the `vector` by reference if you want the function to modify the argument:

```
void merge_sort(vector<int> &arr) {
                         // ^  by reference
```

Similarly for `merge`:

```
void merge(vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right, vector<int> &arr) {
```